# C++ one liner for "string made out of digits"

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm looking for a short (and fast) code to check whether a string contains only digits, specifically looking for a one liner. This is my temporary code:

```
bool IsNumber(const std::string& str)
{
    int i = 0;
    for( ; i<str.size() && isdigit(str[i]); ++i);

    return ( i == str.size() );
}
```

Comment: **I wanted to answer that is was closed** `std::cout << std::regex_search( string, std::regex( "\\d+" ) );`

Answer (score 6):

Use [std::all_of](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/all_any_none_of) along with `isdigit`:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <cctype>
//..
bool allDigits = (!str.empty() && std::all_of(str.begin(), str.end(), ::isdigit));
```

Edit:  Added check for an empty string.

Comment: What if the string is empty?

Comment: Very nice; I suggest the use of `cbegin()` and `cend()` instead of `begin()`/`end()` (but not sure it's usefull)

Comment: @ChristianHackl - `std::all_of` returns `true` for an empty range.

Comment: @RustyX: I could have sworn it returned `false`, because that would make more sense to me, but to my astonishment it returns `true` in that case.

Comment: Just add  && !str.empty() to the line

Comment: @AlexZywicki -- Better to check for the empty string first.  This way the `&&` becomes short-circuited if the string is empty, instead of going into the `std::all_of`.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie good catch

Comment: Unfortunately, in order to be portable and avoid undefined behavior, you need to cast the argument of `isdigit` to `unsigned char`, which would require adding a lambda and making this code much uglier.

Comment: The reason `all_of` returns true for an empty range is that it would be an extra test to return false. That would reduce performance in situations where it doesn't matter.

Comment: @RustyX: I would argue that it's not much a matter of performance, but logic: the sum of an empty range is 0 (the neutral value for sum) and the product of an empty range is 1 (neutral value of product); `all_of` is repeated `and`, and the neutral element of `and` is `true`. The fact that it saves a branch in the implementation is just a consequence of the "obviousness" of this choice.

Comment: @RustyX It isn't due to performance. In logic, for an empty set it is always true that a predicate holds for all of its elements: see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuous_truth.

Comment: @interjay: OTOH, if you use a lambda anyway, then you can easily turn this into a `std::any_of` call with a negated predicate (`!isdigit`) and don't need the `empty()` check anymore.

Comment: i.e. `!std::any_of(begin(s), end(s), [](char c) { return !::isdigit(static_cast<unsigned char>(c)); });` - whether that's better than before or not, I don't know. I guess I'd wrap it in a `bool all_digits(std::string const& s)` function anyway :)

Comment: @ChristianHackl That would return true for an empty string, just like omitting the `empty` check in the `all_of` version.